# Making get request for same domain giving CORS error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web, cors

In a browser extension, this my ajax call

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', window.location.href, true);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.onload = function(event) {
  alert(this.response);
};
```

I really do not understand why this giving me the error

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://people.cs.aau.dk/~torp/Teaching/E01/Oop/handouts/collections.pdf. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)

CORS comes into picture only once we are making the calls to other domain. But here I am making the call to the same domain. You can witness that in url  `xhr.open('GET', window.location.href, true);`

What I am missing here ?

[image]

Comment: Where is the code running that is giving this error? Your screenshot appears to be the built-in PDF viewer. Knowing the execution context of this code is important.

Comment: Depends on where the javascript code was loaded from.

Comment: @MikeTrpcic Code is running in an browser extension. Is there anyway I can avoid this error ?

Comment: @SameerNaik Code is running in an browser extension. Is there anyway I can avoid this error ?

Comment: You can add ACAO (Access Control Allow origin) header from server. http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: @SameerNaik Since this extension can run on anypage, I cannot this on server side.

Comment: @SureshAtta Its a response header, not a request header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118278/discussion-between-ss--and-sameer-naik).

Comment: Your server needs to send the Allow Origin header in it's response for this to work. Browser extensions don't run in the context of the web page currently in view, they have their own context.

Comment: @MikeTrpcic I can't since every web page have it's own server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a web service such as [CrossOrigin.me](https://crossorigin.me/) to get ahead of it. I used a code like this and it did work for me:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://crossorigin.me/http://people.cs.aau.dk/~torp/Teaching/E01/Oop/handouts/collections.pdf',
  jsonpCallback: 'callback',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L84u10yj/**

I was able to make it working here:

[image: Preview]