# CORS Error on Same Domain

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is a segment of my ajax request

```
$.ajax({
url: url,
type:"POST",
crossDomain:true,
data: new FormData(this),
contentType: false,
cache: false,
processData: false,
```

The url points to a controller, everything is on the same domain.
I am using codeigniter, I have these headers set in both my controller and htaccess

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'); 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, content-type, X-Token, x-token');
```

I have read all the solutions on these links
[Making get request for same domain giving CORS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580731/making-get-request-for-same-domain-giving-cors-error)
[CORS error on same domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966707/cors-error-on-same-domain)
and others but still not working. Please any suggestion?

This is the error
    Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading        the remote resource at "the link". (Reason: missing token ‘access-control-allow-headers’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel).

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: why are you using `crossDomain:true`? This causes requests on the same domain to be treated as if they were cross-domain. Is there a very good reason you need to do this? Because if not, you're just making life more complicated for yourself.

Comment: @ADyson I added it because of what was suggested to me on a platform. It wasn;t working before I added it, still not working after it.

Comment: well it definitely won't help you to include it, so remove it. You say "everything is on the same domain", but if you're getting a CORS error _without_ `crossDomain:true`, then we need to check some things: "Same domain" in ajax terms means the client and server must have _exactly_ the same domain, the same protocol (http/https), and the same port number. Can you show the URL of your web page, and the full URL you're ajax-ing to? If those are all correct, then we can start looking at the headers.

Comment: This is the url of the web page: http://scoopnews.info/. This is the page i am ajaxing it to http://scoopnews.info/News/upload/10 @ADyson

Comment: `headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token, methods,method'  }` If you were using CORS, these are headers that the **server** should set, not the client.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147700/discussion-between-user2983401-and-adyson).